# A method of distinguishing Iverson from other brackets?

Tags: conditionals, brackets

Is there a common idiom or method for distinguishing [Iverson brackets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket) from "normal" brackets?

In all examples I've seen, simple braces `[...]` are used for both; but in [complex expressions](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1684700/12400), this can become confusing, as the only way to resolve which is which is by looking closely for the presence of an `=`.

Is there a good way to distinguish these typographically?

Comment: (Aside: Pairs of square brackets are used in many notational conventions, not just for Iverson brackets.) One of the principal obligations of any author is to avoid creating (unnecessary) confusion. If an author believes it's essential to use the Iverson-bracket notation to denote indicator functions, he/she should make every effort not to use square brackets in ways that denote other forms of usage -- at least not in one and the same expression. E.g., one could use pairs of round parentheses and/or curly braces instead of square brackets.

Comment: @Mico: Yes, but the question is about typography, specifically TeX.

Comment: I guess I expressed my typography-related view too implicitly in my earlier comment. A bit more explicitly, then: Unless one is willing and able to add salient visual markers (tildes, above or below the brackets?; horns?; little bells?) to one set of square brackets and not to other(s), the chances that your readers will be confused to no end if you assign different meanings to various pairs of square brackets are just too great to tolerate. Either switch to other symbols (e.g., round parentheses, curly braces) for the "fences", or use another notational convention for the indicator function.

Comment: @Mico: Ah, I see: some unnecessary confusion. So the answer to the question asked is: "no"?

Comment: In the section entitled "Iverson's convention" in the article [Two notes on notation](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9205211), Knuth is noticeably (but certainly not surprisingly) careful *not* to use square brackets for more than one purpose in equations. (Square brackets are also used in the article to offset numerical citation call-outs, but that's outside the equation context that's relevant for Iverson bracket notation.)

Comment: @Mico: Good link! Yes, it appears that there's no convention for something distinctive (e.g., bold brackets, or some other symbols) and that the way to go is to avoid mixing normal and Iverson braces where they will be hard to distinguish.

Answer (score 6):

You can use double brackets for Iverson brackets. In latex mathmode, you can use: `\llbracket` from the `stmaryrd` package. In latex textmode, you can use: `\textlbrackdbl` from the `textcomp` package. Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\begin{document}


$\llbracket Iverson~Brackets~in~mathmode \rrbracket$
\textlbrackdbl Iverson Brackets in textmode \textrbrackdbl


\end{document}
```

The above will compile and look like the following:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Double-set brackets is quite common. One can implement this with `\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\iverson}{\llbracket}{\rrbracket}`
and simply type `\iverson{P}`.
One needs to have `\usepackage{mathtools}` and `\usepackage{stmaryrd}` for this to work.

Comment: With some fonts other than defualt Computer Modern, it would not be necessary to use package `stmaryd`. This is the case for example, with using package `newtx` for all the fonts.